# How do I split without removing delimeter, if it's whitespace

Tags: python, regex, string, split

Here's what I want

```
split('number1+number2')
-->['number1', '+', 'number2']
```

and

```
split('number1 * number2')
-->['number1', '*', 'number2']
```

I'd like split on *, + and -, but keep them. So I tried to do `re.split('(\W+)', mystring)`, which worked but it kept the whitespaces too. What should I do?

Comment: combining map with re seems to actually be faster than any pure regex solution `map(str.strip,re.split('([\*\-\+])', s)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[^\w\s]` matches a character that is neither a word character nor whitespace, so you can use

```
>>> re.split(r"\s*([^\w\s]+)\s*",'number1 * number2')
['number1', '*', 'number2']
```

or, as a verbose regex:

```
re.split(
    r"""\s*   # Match (but don't capture) optional whitespace characters
    (         # Capture...
     [^\w\s]+ # one or more non-whitespace, non-alphanumeric characters
    )         # End of capturing group
    \s*       # Match (but don't capture) optional whitespace characters""", 
    'number1 * number2', flags=re.VERBOSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
In [13]: import re

In [14]: re.split(r'\s*([*+-])\s*',s)
Out[14]: ['number1', '*', 'number2']

In [15]: re.split(r'\s*([*+-])\s*','number1 * number2')   
Out[15]: ['number1', '*', 'number2']

In [16]: re.split(r'\s*([*+-])\s*','number1+number2')   
Out[16]: ['number1', '+', 'number2'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
^(.*?)\s*([+*-])\s*(.*)$
```

Its easier to match and grab the captures.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/iZ9sO5/6

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall):

```
>>> s1 = 'number1+number2'
>>> s2 = 'number1 * number2'
>>> s3 = 'number1 * number2*number3- foo -bar'
>>> r = re.compile(r'\w+|[*+-]')
>>> r.findall(s1)
['number1', '+', 'number2']
>>> r.findall(s2)
['number1', '*', 'number2']
>>> r.findall(s3)
['number1', '*', 'number2', '*', 'number3', '-', 'foo', '-', 'bar']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the *ungreedy* matching :

```
re.split("\s*(\W+?]+)\s*",'number1 * number2')
```

gives correctly `['number1', '*', 'number2']`